# Selenium / Python: Selecting a link from a long list after finding the correct location

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The company has a list of 100+ sites that I am trying to use Selenium webdriver to automatically take a user into that site. I am fairly new to programming so please forgive me if my question is worded poorly.. But, I am trying to take the name of a site such as "**Alpharetta - Cemex**" in the example below from the user and find it in this long list and then select that link. Through testing I am pretty sure the element I need to click is the **h3 class** that also holds the name of the site under the **data-hmi-name**

Website Code Example:
[image]

I have tried to use the below and it never seems to work..

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3.tru-card-head-text uk-text-center[data-hmi-name='Alpharetta - Cemex']").click()
 
#For this one I tried to select the h3 class by searching for all those elements that has the name Alpharetta - Cemex
```

or

```
**theCards = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")** #I tried both of these declarations for theCards
**#theCards = main.find_elements_by_class_name("tru-card-wrapper")**

#then used the loop below. This obviously didn't work and it just returns an error that card.text doesn't actually exist

for card in theCards:
    #title = card.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")
    print(card.text)
    if(card.text == theSite):
        card.click()
```

Any help or guidance would be so appreciated! I am new to programming in Python and if you can explain what I am doing wrong I'd be forever thankful!

Comment: mate welcome to world of coding. Can you tell what error /issue you faced with your current code. Also you should always share your HTML in text format rather than snippet. I would be able to help you in a much better way if you share the all above info.

Comment: Sorry Rahul! Next time I'll be sure to do that.

Comment: Dont be sorry mate, we all are here to learn. Happy learning and cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to click a single link (e.g. Alpharetta - Cemex) , you can try like below:

```
theSite = "Alpharetta - Cemex" #You can store user inputted site Name here
linkXpath = "//a[h3[contains(text(),'"+theSite +"']]"
    
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, linkXpath))).click() #This will wait for element to be clickable before it clicks
```

In case above is not working. If your Link is not in screen / not visible. You can use **java script to first scroll to element and the click** like below:

```
ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, linkXpath)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", ele )
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ele )
```

**You need to Import:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks so much Rahul. Can't tell you how helpful and clear that all is.

Comment: Happy to help mate. Please up vote if it helps you to solve your issue. It will help me and others in turn :). Cheers !!!!